# How are shells for robotic arms made?

Tags: robotic-arm

I wonder how the shells of robotic arms are usually made. By the shell, I mean this:

[image]
[image]

This is taken from the project [here](https://youtu.be/t2eO4CD-0WY), which is a University project. If the shells were injection moulded, how would a university project have sufficient funding for the moulds? Even if the work was contracted to prototyping companies, it'd cost a few thousand of dollars for just one part. If not injection moulding, how are the shells made?

Comment: The image might be from a university project, but the arm is from Kinova: https://www.kinovarobotics.com/en The Arms from UR (first image) are aluminum tubes.

Comment: The university project was probably not to build a new robot, but to use an existing one for a specific task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the comment of @FooBar on the Jaco Arm (The one from the Video), it use  [Carbon Fiber as links](https://www.kinovarobotics.com/sites/default/files/BR-004_KINOVA_JACO_Assistive_Robot-Brochure_EN_R05_0.pdf)

The old ones also used [Plastic links](https://www.kinovarobotics.com/sites/default/files/ULWS-RA-MIC-UG-INT-EN%20201804-1.0%20%28KINOVA%20MICO%E2%84%A2%20Robotic%20arm%20user%20guide%29_0.pdf) with carbon fiber paint effect

You can [copy the carbon fiber effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8smTt.jpg) easily if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Yaskawa Motoman, Rethink Robotics, Kuka, Fanuc or ABB the shells are cast (aluminium in most cases). Older (Kuka) industrial robots have a welded steel structure casing, but you rarely see operational ones with welded steel structure.